# Is it possible to use empty image file as adoptable storage?

Tags: android

I created a 1Gb image file using `dd` command in sdcard. Instead of using the actual sdcard as adoptable storage, i want to use the image file I created.

q: Is it possible to use image file as adoptable storage? how to do it?

Comment: Ok. And what is the question?

Comment: is it possible to use image file as adoptable storage? how to do it?

Comment: Ehh .. put your question in your post. Write a decent post to begin with i would say.